# Какое из выражений корректно: "сыграть друг с другом" или "сыграть между собой"?

Tags: стилистика

Вопрос знатокам-стилистам. Насколько корректно выражение "сыграть между собой"? Допустимо ли оно вообще? Или правильнее — "играть друг с другом"?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, оба варианта допустимы и широко распространены. Но выражение **между собой** имеет некоторые ограничения в употреблении, поэтому важно знать контекст. Например, два человека могут познакомиться **друг с другом**, но не **между собой**. Супруги могут развестись **друг с другом**, но не **между собой**. Вот пример с глаголом **играть**: вряд ли можно сказать, что *дети играют в прятки **между собой***.

Comment: речь идет о конкретном выражении (из мира спорта): команды сыграли между собой 2 раза. Или все же - друг с другом?

Comment: @user189265 Оба варианта корректны.

Answer (score 0):

Надёжный вариант — "играть друг с другом" или "играть друг против друга".
"Между" часто употребляется с "разыграть".

Розенталь, "Управление в русском языке":

> ИГРАТЬ во что / на чём / **с кем-чем** / **против кого-чего** / чем / (реже) с
>   чем. Играть в футбол; Играть на бильярде; Играть с хорошим партнёром;
>   Играть с сильной хоккейной командой; Играть против чемпиона мира;
>   Играть против зарубежного футбольного клуба; Играть кистями пояса;
>   Тарас играл чайной ложкой, вертя её между пальцами (М. Г.); Обезьяна
>   играла с нашими вещами. Ё Играть с огнём [легкомысленно обращаться с
>   чем-л. опасным].

Comment: Вы несколько странно трактуете словарь управления. По Вашей логике и разговаривать между собой нельзя, и драться, и многое другое тоже.