# "Друг другу" и "между собой"

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Все диаметры равны друг другу" и "Все диаметры равны между собой" — одинаково уместные формулировки?

"Друг другу" можно употреблять на тех же основаниях, что и "между собой"?

Comment: Все эти трубы (или иные предметы круглого сечения) _равны по диаметру_.

Comment: По поводу второго вопроса посмотрите также [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458165/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9).

Answer (score 1):

Все диаметры равны друг другу? А так вообще-то говорят? Что-то здесь  со стилистикой не так. Обычно говорится о равенстве предметов, а не о длине отрезков.

Так что скажите проще: ***это равные диаметры.*** Или:  равны между собой (если их сравнивать)

[Друг друга. Фразеологический словарь](https://phraseologiya.academic.ru/334/%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0)

Comment: Представьте себе окружность. Можно провести бесконечно много диаметров этой окружности (диаметром является любая хорда, проходящая через центр окружности). Одно из свойств окружности, которое изучают в школе: **все диаметры окружности равны между собой**. Такая формулировка встречается в самых добротных учебниках советских времён (и досоветских, наверное, тоже).

Comment: Ну ладно, я не против. А друг другу они тоже равны?  Могут быть взаимно равные диаметры?

Comment: "Друг другу" в данном случае мне режет слух. Хотя формально считается, что почти всегда "между собой" можно заменить на "друг другу" (но не наоборот; пару дней тому я изучал этот вопрос). В математике вместо "равны друг другу" чаще говорят "попарно равны".

Comment: Это еще хуже. Попарно - это по двое, парами.